# ASRock Extreme Tuning fan control will not return to silent mode after lowering temperature

Tags: cpu, motherboard, fan, cooling, temperature

I have an Asrock Z77 Pro3, I updated it today to the latest bios version available.
I use the ASRock Extreme Tuning application to control my CPU and case fan, both PWM.

Everything works perfectly / silently when the load is low, when the temperature gets over my set threshold the fans start doing their work.
I wait for them to be silent again but this simply never happens...
If I open the ASRock Extreme Tuning fan control software and check the temp values I see that all is back in normal range but the fans keep on violently whirring.

If I simply click on "Apply" the settings (without changing what is already there) the fans become silent immediately.

Sadly, next time it happens, it behaves identically as explained before.
It feels like the tool is never polling for Temps again after the high temp trigger...

Do you have any suggestion?

Comment: Did you try updating BIOS, Chipset (if applicable), and Power Driver?

Comment: As explained in the post the BIOS was updated today.
All drivers are also fully up to date.

Comment: Apologies. I don't think I saw that when first reading the post.  Is there a Tuner Control update available? Have you contacted Vendor Support?

Comment: The Vendor Support is expired (more than 2 years old) and yes, the Software was also updated today.
I tried everything I could think of, I am a bit lost.

Comment: One thought is to uninstall this software and let Windows and the regular drivers run the fan and see if that works more reliably.

Comment: I think that those fans are being regulated by the BIOS on the Asrock motherboard so they will just follow whatever is set in the BIOS. The only thing I can try is to remove the application and try only BIOS.